# Is there a possibility to skip rows and start a pivot table from the 8th row?

Tags: python, excel, pandas

```
I have the following function using the following dependencies

import win32com.client as win32
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
from pathlib import Path
import re
import sys
win32c = win32.constants

def run_excel(f_path: Path, f_name: str, sheet_name: str):

    filename = f_path / f_name

    # create excel object
    excel = win32.gencache.EnsureDispatch('Excel.Application')

    # excel can be visible or not
    excel.Visible = True  # False
    
    # try except for file / path
    try:
        wb = excel.Workbooks.Open(filename)
    except com_error as e:
        if e.excepinfo[5] == -2146827284:
            print(f'Failed to open spreadsheet.  Invalid filename or location: {filename}')
        else:
            raise e
        sys.exit(1)

    # set worksheet
    ws1 = wb.Sheets('GRC User Data Clean Up')
```

However, my ws1 has headers that start at row 9. How do I specify this with win32?

I want to skip the first eight rows

Please help!

Then I want to create a pivot table from the eight row down until 12000;

```
    def run_excel(f_path: Path, f_name: str, sheet_name: str):
    
        filename = f_path / f_name
    
        # create excel object
        excel = win32.gencache.EnsureDispatch('Excel.Application')
    
        # excel can be visible or not
        excel.Visible = True  # False
        
        # try except for file / path
        try:
            wb = excel.Workbooks.Open(filename)
        except com_error as e:
            if e.excepinfo[5] == -2146827284:
                print(f'Failed to open spreadsheet.  Invalid filename or location: {filename}')
            else:
                raise e
            sys.exit(1)
    
        # set worksheet
        ws1 = wb.Sheets('GRC User Data Clean Up')
        
        # Setup and call pivot_table
        ws2_name = 'pivot_table'
        wb.Sheets.Add().Name = ws2_name
        ws2 = wb.Sheets(ws2_name)
        
        # update the pt_name, pt_rows, pt_cols, pt_filters, pt_fields at your preference
        pt_name = 'example'  # pivot table name, must be a string
        pt_rows = ['Access Risk ID', 'User ID','User Group','Execution Hit on Both Sides?', 'Risk Description']  # rows of pivot table, must be a list
        # pt_cols = []  # columns of pivot table, must be a list
        pt_filters = ['Final verdict','Execution Hit on Both Sides?' ]  # filter to be applied on pivot table, must be a list
        # [0]: field name [1]: pivot table column name [3]: calulation method [4]: number format (explain the list item of pt_fields below)
        pt_fields = [['Access Risk ID', 'Access Risk ID', win32c.xlCount, '0'],  # must be a list of lists
                     ['User ID', 'User ID', win32c.xlCount, '0'],
                     ['User Group', 'User Group', win32c.xlCount, '0'],
                     ['Execution Hit on Both Sides?', 'Execution Hit on Both Sides?', win32c.xlCount, '0'],
                     ['Risk Description', 'Risk Description', win32c.xlCount, '0']]
        # calculation method: xlAverage, xlSum, xlCount
        pivot_table(wb, ws1, ws2, ws2_name, pt_name, pt_rows, pt_filters, pt_fields)
        wb.Save() # save the pivot table created
    #    wb.Close(True)
    #    excel.Quit()


def pivot_table(wb: object, ws1: object, pt_ws: object, ws_name: str, pt_name: str, pt_rows: list, pt_filters: list, pt_fields: list):
    """
    wb = workbook1 reference
    ws1 = worksheet1 that contain the data
    pt_ws = pivot table worksheet number
    ws_name = pivot table worksheet name
    pt_name = name given to pivot table
    pt_rows, pt_cols, pt_filters, pt_fields: values selected for filling the pivot tables
    """

    # pivot table location
    pt_loc = len(pt_filters) + 2
    
    # grab the pivot table source data
    pc = wb.PivotCaches().Create(SourceType=win32c.xlDatabase, SourceData=ws1.UsedRange)
    
    # create the pivot table object
    pc.CreatePivotTable(TableDestination=f'{ws_name}!R{pt_loc}C1', TableName=pt_name)

    # selecte the pivot table work sheet and location to create the pivot table
    pt_ws.Select()
    pt_ws.Cells(pt_loc, 1).Select()

    # Sets the rows, columns and filters of the pivot table
    for field_list, field_r in ((pt_filters, win32c.xlPageField), 
                                (pt_rows, win32c.xlRowField)):
        for i, value in enumerate(field_list):
            pt_ws.PivotTables(pt_name).PivotFields(value).Orientation = field_r
            pt_ws.PivotTables(pt_name).PivotFields(value).Position = i + 1

    # Sets the Values of the pivot table
    for field in pt_fields:
        pt_ws.PivotTables(pt_name).AddDataField(pt_ws.PivotTables(pt_name).PivotFields(field[0]), field[1], field[2]).NumberFormat = field[3]

    # Visiblity True or False
    pt_ws.PivotTables(pt_name).ShowValuesRow = True
    pt_ws.PivotTables(pt_name).ColumnGrand = True
```

I have found the following resources, however, none of them seem to be working:
https://www.automateexcel.com/vba/xldown-xlup-xltoright-xltoleft/

used range gives back a range:

```
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/excel.worksheet.usedrange
```

Comment: `SourceData=ws1.UsedRange` This takes the whole used range as source. Probably you can delimit here the range properly as you wish

Comment: @FoxfireAndBurnsAndBurns thanks but how would I do that?

Comment: I don't know the notation in Python but to specify a range in VBA the notation would be, as example, `ws1.Range("A9:C30")` This notation means your whole data goes from Cell A9 (top left cell) to cell C30 (bottom right cell) and headers are in the first row always (9 in this example)